# Match words beginning with an uppercase letter until a word beginning with an uppercase letter

Tags: regex

I would like to match words in a line that start with an uppercase letter and continue until the word (s) that begin with the other uppercase letter begin.

```
Animals Chicken helmet Animal baby kids Crazy 6 yo monkey Baby white-black horse
```

Match: / contains lowercase letters, numbers, special characters

`Animals` `Chicken helmet` `Animal baby kids` `Crazy 6 yo monkey` `Baby white-black horse`

i tried this

```
(^[A-Za-z]+\s?\w+\W+?\d?)+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
\b[A-Z]\S*(?:\s+[^A-Z\s]\S*)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wWPs2o/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (if the words are separated with whitespaces, replace with `(?<!\S)`)
- `[A-Z]\S*` - an uppercase ASCII letter (replace with `\p{Lu}` if supported for Unicode support) and then any zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\s+[^A-Z\s]\S*)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `[^A-Z\s]` - any char but whitespace and an uppercase ASCII letter (use `[^\p{Lu}\s]` if Uniocde support is necessary and is supported)
  - `\S*` - any zero or more non-whitespace chars